# UITest. How to check if keyboard exists?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios9, xcode-ui-testing

`XCTAssertTrue(app.keyboards.elementBoundByIndex(0).exists)` causes crash. How to do this then? Is it possible to check whether keaboard exists at all?

Answer (score 5):

`XCTAssertEqual(app.keyboards.count, 1)` - keyboard exists.
`XCTAssertEqual(app.keyboards.count, 0)` - keyboard doesn't exists.

Comment: Is there a way I can dismiss the keyboard if it exists?

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to check if the textField contains `Keyboard Focused`

```
let emailTextField = app.textFields.element(boundBy: 0)
XCTAssertTrue(emailTextField.debugDescription.contains("Keyboard Focused")))
```